# Julia: converting CHOLMOD factor to sparse matrix and back again

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization, suitesparse

I have a CHOLMOD factorization of a sparse matrix `H`, and I want to edit the sparse representation of the upper, lower, and block diagonal factors. How can I do this? When I run the below, the last line doesn't work.

```
H = sprand(10,10,0.5)
fac = ldltfact(H; shift=0.0)
fD = fac[:D]
D = Base.SparseArrays.CHOLMOD.Sparse(fD)
```

And is there any way to go in the reverse direction from a sparse matrix to a `CHOLMOD.factor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the relevant factorization matrices of `ldltfact` can be a little tedious. The following example shows an example similar to the one in the question with a final test that the extracted matrices recover the original factorized one:

```
srand(1)
pre = sprand(10,10,0.5)
H = pre + pre' + speye(10,10)

fac = ldltfact(H; shift=0.0)
P = sparse(1:size(H,1),fac[:p],ones(size(H,1)))
LD = sparse(fac[:LD]) # this matrix contains both D and L embedded in it

L = copy(LD)
for i=1:size(L,1)
  L[i,i] = 1.0
end

D = sparse(1:size(L,1),1:size(L,1),diag(LD))

PHP = P*H*P'
LDL = L*D*L'

using Base.Test
@test PHP ≈ LDL
```

The expected output (and actual on Julia v0.6.3):

```
julia> @test PHP ≈ LDL
Test Passed
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Is there any way to extract the block diagonal factor `D` in sparse form from `LD`? I as because I need to perform a positive definite modification to the 0 and negative eigenvalues, and I don't want to change the whole matrix by performing the factorization with an entire diagonal modification.

Comment: Suppose that I've edited the sparse representation of `LD`. Is there any nice way to convert it back to a `CHOLMOD.factor`? (per edit)

Comment: @jjjjjj Don't think it is easy to convert the edited `LD` into a CHOLMOD.factor, since the functions are basically wrappers around the CHOLMOD library interface. But with the factorization available, the linear algebra should be faster without getting back to use CHOLMOD. The fast `solve` is defined for triangular matrices also.