# Julia ldlfact and sparse conversion

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a linear system in Julia with `ldlfact`. Why am I getting different results in the following cases?

*Setup*:

```
srand(10)
n = 7
pre = sprand(n,n,0.5)
H = pre + pre' + speye(n,n)
p_true = rand(n)
g = H*-p_true
fac = ldltfact(H; shift=0.0)
perm = fac[:p]
p1 = zeros(n)
p2 = zeros(n)
```

*Case 1*:

```
LDs = sparse(fac[:LD])
q1 = LDs\-g[perm]
p1[perm] = fac[:U]\q1
H*p - H*p_true
```

*Case 2*:

```
q2 = fac[:LD]\-g[perm]
p2[perm] = fac[:U]\q2
H*p2 - H*p_true
```

The solution `p1` is wrong in the first case.

Comment: Any specific reason why you access internal fields of the factorization? Why don't you just do x = ldltfact(A) \ b to solve Ax = b?

Comment: `sparse(fac[:LD])` should not be used in algebra, as it is basically a "montage" of the matrix `L` with the diagonal `D`. As a regular sparse matrix, the operations (`\ `, etc.) can be used, but the results could be unexpected and wrong - as you discovered. To correctly solve using `LDs`, separate it to `D` and `L` and solve, `L*D*Lt \ -g[perm]`. To do it faster you could first solve `Lt \ -g[perm]` and then `D \ result` and so on (using right matrix multiplication associativity).

Comment: @fredrikekre: I would, but I need to perform a positive definite modification where I change any of the block diagonal elements corresponding to an eigenvalue <= 0 to some positive delta. And I'd prefer not to modify the entire diagonal using `shift=delta`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't post this nicely as a comment, so wanted to add for posterity. Solving *Case 1* in the following way worked for this example (thanks to @DanGetz's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494948/julia-converting-cholmod-factor-to-sparse-matrix-and-back-again/48506723?noredirect=1#comment84032952_48506723))

```
L = copy(LDs)
for i=1:size(L,1)
  L[i,i] = 1.0
end
D = sparse(1:size(L,1),1:size(L,1),diag(LDs))

q1 = (L*D)\-g[perm]
p1[perm] = L'\q1
H*p1 - H*p_true
```